# asp core 2.1 перенаправление для авторизации, теряем порт

Tags: .net-core

Сервер за nat. наружу прокинут порт. 
Cайт открывается по адресу http://10.10.10.10:7171
При попытке зайти на страницу, которая требует авторизация, идет перенаправление на url: [http://10.10.10.10/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=....и](http://10.10.10.10/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=....%D0%B8) т.д.
т.е. теряется порт 7171...как сделать, чтобы при перенаправлении не терялся порт?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Все оказалось проще.
В настройках nginx поставил порт в параметре:
proxy_set_header Host $host:7171

Вроде теперь все ок.

еще покопался, заменить директиву

```
$host:port
```

на директиву

```
$http_host
```

тогда порт указывать не надо, все отрабатывает корректно.